# Styles not getting applied properly in dynamically created rating star plugin in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using the jquery rating star plugin and everything works ok when I use statically, but when I create a listview dynamically and I place the "option" input control inside, it never applies the styles.

In the  I have loaded the stylesheets:

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
   <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"/> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/rating/jquery.rating.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/etensr.theme.css" />
   <script src="jquery.1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rating/jquery.rating.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile.1.0.min.js"></script>       
</head>
```

and the page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="subcategories" data-theme="a">
    <div class="header" data-role="header" style="height: 42px;" >  
        <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="c">Back</a>
        <a href="order.html" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-right">0.00 SRD - </a>                                 
    </div>        
    <div data-role="content" id="subcategoryCnt">
      <ul id="subcategoryList" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="c" >
        <li data-icon="arrow-r" > 
           <img src="images/thumb80x80.jpg" />
           <div>
              <div style="float:left;"><p>Product</p></div>
              <div style="float:right;font-size: 12px;">Price</div>    
              <div style="clear:both;"></div>
              <div style="float:left;">
                 <input name="star1" type="radio" data-role="none" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
                 <input name="star1" type="radio" data-role="none" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
                 <input name="star1" type="radio" data-role="none" class="star" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
              </div>
           </div>           
        </li>    
      </ul>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

All this is displayed properly but when I load the listview items dynamically the input radios are not rendered like stars but normal radiobuttons:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="subcategories" data-theme="a">
    <div class="header" data-role="header" style="height: 42px;" >  
        <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="c">Back</a>
        <a href="order.html" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-right">0.00 SRD - </a>                                 
    </div>        
    <div data-role="content" id="subcategoryCnt">
        <script type="text/javascript">
           GetSubcategories(); 
        </script>                                    
    </div>
 </div>
```

and the JS is:

```
function GetSubcategories() {
   subcategories = result.GetSubcategoriesResult;
   if (subcategories.length > 0) {
      var html = '<ul id="subcategoryList" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="c" >';
      for (i = 0; i < subcategories.length; i++) {
          html = html + '<li data-role="list-divider">' + subcategories[i].Name + '</li>';
          prods = subcategories[i].Products;
          if (prods.length > 0) {
              for (j = 0; j < prods.length; j++) {
                  html = html +
                      '<li data-icon="arrow-r" >' +
                        '<a href="products.html"  rel="external">' +
                            '<img src="images/thumb80x80.jpg" />' +
                            '<div>' +
                               '<div style="float:left;"><p>' + prods[j].Name + '</p></div>' +
                               '<div style="float:right;font-size: 12px;">' + prods[j].Price + ' SRD</div>' +
                               '<div style="clear:both;"></div>' +
                               '<div style="float:left;">' +
                                    '<input name="star' + prods[j].Id + '" type="radio" data-role="none" class="star" disabled="disabled" />' +
                                    '<input name="star' + prods[j].Id + '" type="radio" data-role="none" class="star" disabled="disabled" />' +
                                    '<input name="star' + prods[j].Id + '" type="radio" data-role="none" class="star" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>' +
                               '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</a>' +
                      '</li>';
              }
          }
      }
          html += '</ul>';
   }
   $('#subcategoryCnt').html(html);
   $('#subcategoryList').listview();    
}
```

When I do the same but dynamically everything is displayed properly except the input radio which is not displayed like stars.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about `data-icon="star"`

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

Also I think you still need to refresh jQM

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

JS

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Thanks Phill but it doesn't solve my problem. I still don't know why styles, besides of the jquerymobile styles, are not being applied when I create controls dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try using live query, because when you do $(selector).rating(); , the plugin is applied to the elements defined by the selector that are present in the DOM. When you add them dynamically, you need to apply the plugin to them on the fly too. That is where livequery can help you. Do something like

> $(selector).livequery(function(){
>                      $(this).rating();  // OR add the options that u want
>            });